# Swift comparing Strings optionals vs non-optional

Tags: ios, swift

When comparing strings in Swift, you can compare non-optional strings with optional strings.

Like so (text is an optional, and it is empty):

```
UITextField.text == "" // True
```

Is it because the equality operator unwraps Strings by itself?

Comment: is that your actual code? because `UITextField` class doesn't have a `text` property

Comment: That is just an example. I have initialised an UITextField, and it has an attribute called text.

You can see it here:
https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UITextField_Class/

Comment: There is no unwrapping, the equality is just defined on optionals, too and a non-optional can be automatically promoted to an optional.

Comment: Looks like you are confusing a nil value with an empty string. If the 'text' variable is nil, that is not the same as an empty string, it means there is no string at all. So your test should fail.

Answer (score 24):

For every `Equatable` type the `==` operation is also defined for optionals:

```
public func ==<T : Equatable>(lhs: T?, rhs: T?) -> Bool
```

The non-optional on the right side gets automatically promoted to an optional.

The `==` for optionals returns `true` when both values are `nil` or if they are both non-nil and they are equal.

Comment: Side note: the corresponding *comparison* operators taking optional arguments will be removed in Swift 3: https://github.com/apple/swift-evolution/blob/master/proposals/0121-remove-optional-comparison-operators.md.

Answer (score 2):

Your theory doesn’t hold in the following example:

```
let x: String? = nil

if x == "" {
    print("True")
} else {
    print("False") //Printed
}
```

What’s actually happening here is that the `text` property is never actually `nil` upon initialisation — it is instead an empty string, as given by the [documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UITextField_Class/#//apple_ref/occ/instp/UITextField/text):

> This string is @"" by default.

The Swift compiler does not implicitly unwrap any optionals, it instead leaves that responsibility to the programmer.