# swift XCTAssertEquals succeeded with Optional

Tags: swift, option-type, xctest

I have this succeeded test:

```
func testProfileFieldValue() {
   let realm = try! Realm()
   let vs = ["name":"n"]
   createOrUpdate(realm: realm, value: vs)
   let profile = realm.objects(Profile.self).first
   XCTAssertEqual("n", profile?.name)
}
private func createOrUpdate(realm:Realm, value: Any = [:]) {
    try! realm.write() {
      realm.create(Profile.self,value:value,update: true)
    }
}
```

Why did this test succeed? "n" is not an optional. If i try to assert:

```
 XCTAssertEqual("nf", profile?.name)
```

I get this failure message from Xcode:

> XCTAssertEqual failed: ("Optional("nf")") is not equal to
>   ("Optional("n")")

Why "nf" is and Optional?

thx

Comment: `profile?.name` is an optional, therefore `"n"` is "auto-wrapped" by the compiler into an optional as well, so that the two values can be compared. Compare http://stackoverflow.com/a/38587571/1187415.

Answer (score 1):

please try this way [apple suggest](https://blog.codecentric.de/en/2014/10/extending-xctestcase-testing-swift-optionals/)

```
if let profilename= profile?.name {
    XCTAssertEqual("n", profilename)
}
else {
    XCTFail("Value isn't set")
}
```

**UPDATE:** 
@MartinR comment good point out :

> The non-optional on the left side `"nf"` gets automatically promoted to an optional.because  `profile?.name` is an optiona

More check this 
[Swift comparing Strings optionals vs non-optional](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38587273/swift-comparing-strings-optionals-vs-non-optional/38587571#38587571)

Comment: My test succeded even without 'let', I would like to understand why.

Answer (score 1):

What's happening with

```
XCTAssertEqual("nf", profile?.name)
```

is the compiler sees that the second expression evaluates to an optional String. It then implicitly converts the first expression to an optional, in order to do the comparison. This is why the failure message shows both sides as Optional.