# Unit testing DI with CoreData won't work

Tags: ios, swift, unit-testing, core-data, dependency-injection

I'm trying to write a test to make sure that my view model's model property when set calls my fetchPlan method from the model and then sets my 'plan' property in my view model. It seems to be setting the property but the values are missing...

Here's my view model

```
final class PlanProgressViewModel: PlanProgressViewModelView {

// MARK: - Properties
fileprivate var plan: PlanData?

// MARK: - PlanProgressViewModelView
weak var viewDelegate: PlanProgressViewModelViewDelegate?

var model: PlanModel? {
    didSet {
        model?.fetchCurrentPlan(completionHandler: { (plan) in
            guard let plan = plan else {return}
            self.plan = plan
        })
    }
}
// Testing this fails...
var planName: String! {
    guard let plan = plan else {return "No plan"}
    return plan.name
}

var planProgressionString: String! {
    return "\(Int(round(self.progress * 100)))%"
}

var progress: Double! {
    guard let plan = plan, let workouts = plan.workouts, let completedWorkouts = plan.completedWorkouts else {return 0}
    return Double(Int(completedWorkouts) / workouts.count)
}
}
```

Here's my test suite, i'm using a mock to return hardcoded data from the model.

```
var sut: PlanProgressViewModel!
var model: MockPlanModel!
var moc: NSManagedObjectContext!

override func setUp() {
    super.setUp()
    moc = setupInMemoryMOC()

    let mockModel = MockPlanModel(moc: moc)
    model = mockModel

    let viewModel = PlanProgressViewModel()
    viewModel.model = model
    sut = viewModel
}

override func tearDown() {
    moc = nil
    model = nil
    sut = nil
    super.tearDown()
}
// This passes
func testModelFetchesCurrentPlanOnce() {
    XCTAssertEqual(model.fetchPlanWasCalled, 1)
}

// This is failing
func testPlanName() {
    XCTAssertEqual(sut.planName, "Test plan")
}
```

Here's my method for setting up a in memory persistent store...

```
public func setupInMemoryMOC() -> NSManagedObjectContext {
let mom = NSManagedObjectModel.mergedModel(from: [Bundle.main])
let psc = NSPersistentStoreCoordinator(managedObjectModel: mom!)

do {
    try psc.addPersistentStore(ofType: NSInMemoryStoreType, configurationName: nil, at: nil, options: nil)
} catch {
    fatalError()
}

let moc = NSManagedObjectContext.init(concurrencyType: .mainQueueConcurrencyType)
moc.persistentStoreCoordinator = psc

return moc }
```

Here's my mock for the model which returns hardcoded data...

```
public class MockPlanModel: MWPlanModel {
var fetchPlanWasCalled = 0

override public func fetchCurrentPlan(completionHandler: @escaping (_ plan: PlanData?) -> ()) {
    fetchPlanWasCalled += 1

    let moc = setupInMemoryMOC()
    let plan = createTestPlan(moc: moc)

    completionHandler(plan)
}}
```

Here's my helper method for creating the model object, (PlanData is a protocol that my 'Plan' NSManaged object inherits).

```
public func createTestPlan(moc: NSManagedObjectContext) -> PlanData {
let plan: Plan = Plan(context: moc)
plan.name = "Test plan"
plan.completedWorkouts = 5
plan.currentPlan = true

for _ in 0..<5 {
    plan.mutableOrderedSetValue(forKeyPath: #keyPath(Plan.workouts)).add(createTestCompletedWorkout(moc: moc))
}

return plan }
```

The plan name should be "Test plan" as that is what i set the hardcoded value to be but it fails and returns an empty string instead...
[image]

Really stuck on this, i'm fairly new to testing so i appreciate any help with this. Thanks

Comment: would you check my update answer and let me know

Answer (score 0):

@MartinR comment good point out :

> The non-optional on the left side `"Test plan"` gets automatically promoted to an optional. because  `sut.planName` is an optional. more check this [Swift comparing Strings optionals vs non-optional](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38587273/swift-comparing-strings-optionals-vs-non-optional/38587571#38587571)

You need to  unwrap  `sut.planName`

```
if let planName = sut.planName{
   XCTAssertEqual(planName, "Test plan")
}
```

Or try this way :

```
 XCTAssertEqual((sut.planName ?? ""), "Test plan")
```

**Note: If you face still same issue then update your Xcode**

```
// Using Apple XCTest (Xcode 7.3.1), this produces the output:
// "XCTAssertEqual failed: ("Optional(1)") is not equal to ("Optional(2)") - "
XCTAssertEqual(1, 2)
```

More details :  [Here Bug reported](https://bugs.swift.org/browse/SR-1417)

Comment: Hi, thanks for the answer. I didn't realise that could be a potential issue so thanks. It's still failing however, but this time instead of an optional type it's just returning an empty string. I safely unwrapped it and i also updated my Xcode, but still doesn't work.